# Advanced (spoken/human)language translation projects?

Tags: algorithm, language-translation

Are there any language translation projects which do not simply translate word-by-word? One with an advanced algorithm/design?

Current mainstream and popular translation software, such as Google translate, seem to look up a word, or group of sequential words, and translating it directly to what is somehow determined to be the best match. But because it is not context aware, it could grab the wrong word. Additionally, it doesn't understand the language at all, it just tries to decode words, instead of decoding the meaning. Many languages are not similar at all, and do not have corresponding common words and/or their usage is not the same at all.

Alternatively, I think a better method would be one which could extract meaning or information from a phrase. It would actually decode the meaning, then encode that meaning into a computer readable, intermediary language, and thus be able to decode it completely into a new language.

Are there any such projects, open source or closed, which are making progress on new algorithms for language translation?

Answer (score 1):

The is [Apertium](http://www.apertium.org/) projects seems active (latest release few months ago). Supports many languages. There is also [article](http://linuxgazette.net/152/oregan.html) about it in the context of other translators.